# check with Matlab if object is exsting

Tags: matlab

**Matlab code:**

```
for n = 1:length(data)

    if exist('data{n}.sid')
        array{n} = data{n}.sid
    else
        array{n} = 0
    end

end
```

**Result:**

```
array = 

    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]
```

But in the first and the second struct of "data", the "hk1", resp. the "hk1.sid" exists and contains "1"!

How do I have to change my code, that the array looks like this?...

```
array = 

    [1]    [1]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]
```

**Content of data:**

```
>> data

data = 

    [1x1 struct]    [1x1 struct]    [1x1 struct]    [1x1 struct]    [1x1 struct]    [1x1 struct]    [1x1 struct]

>> data{2}

ans = 

    sid: 1
    hk1: [1x1 struct]

>> data{4}

ans = 

          pack_id: [1x1 struct]
    pack_seq_ctrl: [1x1 struct]
```

As you see, data{2} includes "sid", but data{4} doesn't include "sid"...

Comment: Of course, see the update "Content of data" above. P.S. I wrote something wrong: remove hk1. But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `exist('data{n}.sid')`, use `isstruct(data{n}) && isfield(data{n}, 'sid')`.

`exist` is attempting to check whether a variable exists that is literally called `data{n}.sid`. That's not a valid variable name, so it always returns `false` and you never get through to the condition you wanted.

Comment: Hi Sam, thank you that works fine! But assuming I want to check one level deeper like this: data{n}.hk1.mode, how I have to change the code? That means I want to extract the content of "mode" if hk1 and mode is available.

Comment: @Kevin For that, try out the other solution code after changing `sid` to `mode` in that code?

Comment: You'd have to use `isstruct(data{n}) && isfield(data{n}), 'hk1') && isstruct(data{n}.hk1) && isfield(data{n}.hk1, 'mode')`.

Answer (score 0):

See if this `isfield` + `cellfun` based approach works for you -

```
fn1 = 'hk1' %// stage1 search fieldname
fn2 = 'sid' %// stage2 search fieldname

%// logical array, where 1s mean first stage fieldname 'hk1' exists in data struct
stage1_matches = cellfun(@(x) isfield(x, fn1),data) 

%// get the actual indices as we will need these later on 
stage1_idx = find(stage1_matches) 

%// logical array, where 1s indicate second stage fieldname 'sid' exists in 
%// data.hk1 struct
stage2_matches = cellfun(@(x) isfield(x.hk1,fn2),data(stage1_matches))  

 %// find the indices from stage1_idx where 'sid' fieldname is not  present 
 %// and index into the logical array of stage1_matches to set those as zeros 
 %// and thus we have the desired output
stage1_matches(stage1_idx(~stage2_matches)) = 0
```